# Copy files from a directory if name present in a text file

Tags: shell-script, file-copy

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    cd /home/Sud/Minimal\ Packages/All/
    if [ -d $line ]
    then
        cp $line*.rpm /home/Sud/NewFolder/rpms/
    else
        echo $line>>/home/Sud/NewFolder/notfound.txt
    fi
done < "$1"
```

I am trying to run the above code to

1. Read a text file line by line
2. Search a folder if there is a directory by that name
3. - **a)** if yes; copy contents of that directory to another directory
   - **b)** if not, copy the directory name to another text file.

Each time I run the script, it copies all names to `notfound.txt` even though they are present in the folder I'm searching.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It looks like you have white-spaces in the name. Have you tried `if [ -d "$line" ]` instead?

Comment: I tried running the cp line in shell. It works even if I use 'cp $line*.rpm destination/' instead of using 'cp "$line*.rpm" destination/'

Comment: How about `cp "$line"/*.rpm destination/`

Comment: @1_CR that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if cp "$line"*.rpm destination/ ; then
    echo $line "successful!"
else
    echo $line "not found!"
    echo "$line">> /home/Sud/notfound.txt
fi
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to put every usage of `$line` in double quotes to handle white-spaces properly?

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
cd /home/Sud/Minimal\ Packages/All/
if [ -d "$line" ]
then
    cp "$line*.rpm" /home/Sud/NewFolder/rpms/
else
    echo "$line" >> /home/Sud/NewFolder/notfound.txt
fi
done < "$1"
```

Comment: That didn't work. Everything is still going to 'notfound.txt'

Comment: @SudhanshAggarwal I gave it a try and seemed to have worked for me. Could you please check if you have trailing slash in directories? i.e. `path/to/mydir/` instead of `path/to/mydir`.

Comment: @SudhanshAggarwal you also do `cd /home/Sud/Minimal\ Packages/All/` in your script. Is your directory list relative to that path?

Comment: Yes, directory list is relative to /home/Sud/Minimal\ Packages/

I also removed the trailing slashes from the 'cp' line, didn't give me any different result.

Comment: @SudhanshAggarwal Like I said the script worked just fine for me. Could you please provide some items from your list that supposed to work?

Comment: The first 10 lines from my text file are as follows acl aic94xx-firmware atmel-firmware attr audit audit-libs authconfig b43-openfwwf basesystem bash

Comment: They all should work.

Comment: Could you please confirm that these directories exist in `/home/Sud/Minimal\ Packages/All/` by providing a listing with `ls -al`?

Comment: I tried a different approach and fixed it.   I used <!-- if cp "$line"*.rpm destination/ ; then echo $line "successful!"
else scho $line>>notfound.txt fi -->

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have commented what worked for me. Thanks for your suggestions, I used them too :)